# can't find scp file from remote server on my local machine

Tags: scp

I copied file from remote server, through SSH scp command, on my local machine. using realpath command I see that it exist on my machine but when I try to open it, it says that : no such file or directory
does anyone have idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please post: (1) the `scp` command you used; (2) the `realpath` command you mentioned, plus its output; (3) the command that gives you `no such file or directory`. Be specific. Do not reply in comments, [edit] the question instead.

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. Can you show the exact commands you entered, along with their output?